# Hyperlink highlighting not visible from google pdf viewer

Tags: hyperref

I have a file that has a hyperlink that is visible on a regular viewer, not when you open it as attachment to gmail (if you download it, it becomes visible again). Is there a way to modify highlighting such that hyperlinks are visible in both situations?

**Google viewer:**

[image]

**Local machine viewer:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \item 1986, \href{https://archive.org/details/texprogram00knut}{The \TeX program}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}`? Off-topic: `\TeX{} The Program` is the correct title and `{}` is needed there

Comment: Since Adobe developed the PDF format, if it works on Acrobat then it is right.  If it doesn't work on all viewers, that is the fault of the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @koleygr's answer:

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \item 1986, \href{https://archive.org/details/texprogram00knut}{\TeX{} The program}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

**Google viewer:**

[image]